# datagrid datatable binding and setting specific cell's tooltip and background color

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid bound to a DataTable, with autogeneratecolumns=true because  the datatable can be anything from Excel's files.

But now I want to paint specific cells with red and add a tooltip which is an error message that can be appear in the validation process when the data is loaded from Excel.

My goal is Paint in red all the cells with errors. The errors are in a `List<CError>` where CError may have data like {row=4,col=6,Error=" the date is wrong"} so some cells will have error, and I want to Paint those cells with red and attach to them the error in the tooltip, but I can not find the way. My DataGrid is defined like:

in the Viewmodel I have the "LoadData()" method which runs when some button is pressed, that function is:

```
public List<CError> ErrorInSheet {get;set;}

public void LoadData()
    {
        Sheets= GetSheetsFromExcel(PathExcel);
        SelectedSheet= Sheets.FirstOrDefault();
        MyDataTableFromExcel= LoadDataFromSheet(PathExcel, SelectedSheet);
        ErrorInSheet=ValidateData(MyDataTableFromExcel);

    }
```

and the CError class is this:

```
public class CErrorExcel
{
    public int row { get; set; }
    public int col { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is how can paint in red only the cells in the datagrid which have errors after the validation process, those errors will be in the ErrorInSheet collection

I don't know If I am making a bad approach because I can't find the way yet, of painting cells indicated in the CErrorExcel class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did find the way to do what I asked before, maybe will be usefull to someone some time
I do load the data  from Excel with a viewmodel's method and in that process I créate a collection of errors, In the event handler of loading of my scrollviwer  I put the call to the process wich paint specifcs cells of my dataGrid and set the tooltip too.
This is the code

```
private async void ScrollViewer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await CargaExcelEnGrid();
}


private async Task CargaExcelEnGrid()
{

    try
    {
        await vm.LoadDatafromExcel(); //loading in the viewmodel
        grdExcel.ItemsSource = null;
        grdExcel.ItemsSource = vm.TableExcel.DefaultView;

        foreach (CErrorExcel error in vm.ErrorExcel)
        {
            DataGridCell cell = GetCell(error.row, error.col, grdExcel);
            cell.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
            cell.ToolTip = error.Error;
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception err)
    {
        ModernDialog.ShowMessage(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
public DataGridCell GetCell(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, DataGrid dg)
{
    DataGridRow row = dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
    if (row == null)
    {
        dg.UpdateLayout();
        dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.Items[rowIndex]);
        row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex);
    }
    DataGridCellsPresenter p = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
    DataGridCell cell = p.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(columnIndex) as DataGridCell;
    return cell;
}
```

Works really good, hope this will help to someone.

bye